# How to make static value in dynamic query

Tags: php

Hello this is my code and I want to make it dynamic please provide me a solution on how to do it.

```
$start = strtotime($this->input->post('leave_from'));
$end = strtotime($this->input->post('leave_to'));
$days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400 + 1);

if($this->input->post('leave_type') == 3){
    $days_between = 0.5;
}
```

I want to make this dynamic how to make it m using query.

```
$q = "set leave_applications.days = '0.5' on leave_applications where leave_type = 3 "; 
$days_between = $this->leave_application_model->q_single($q);
```

don't know whether it's correct way or not but it displays an error

> Unknown system variable 'days' set leave_applications.days = '0.5' on
>   leave_applications where leave_type = 3

Help me how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: is your query correct? It doesn't look completely formed to me and the error is stating leave_applications.days doesn't exist

Comment: days exists its only giving error when i select  leave_type = 3 only and remaining works fine

Comment: please make the correct format of query

Comment: try to echo the query that it errors on and paste that into a new query window for the DB. Does it return the same error message?

Comment: this is a purely an SQL question. don't post php code.

Comment: Does this do what your looking for? `UPDATE leave_applications SET days = '0.5' WHERE leave_type = 3`

Comment: then how it can be done

Comment: m using this during insert

Comment: $application = array(
    'leave_from' => $this->input->post('leave_from'), 
    'leave_to' => $this->input->post('leave_to'), 
    'reason' => $this->input->post('reason'), 
    'leave_type' => $this->input->post('leave_type'),
                'days' => $days_between, 
               'leave_status' => 2, 
   );
  $this->leave_application_model->insert($application);

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what your asking for. Could it be your looking for a trigger? The update script could be set to run when an insert is made? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: you understand me wrong  i simply want when i select leave_type = 3 then simply it insert its days as 0.5 only
 if($this->input->post('leave_type') == 3){
    $days_between = 0.5;
} => using this works well i only want to insert this dynamically only instead of giving value i want to insert it through query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `leave_applications` SET `days` = '0.5' WHERE `leave_type` = 3
```

Comment: Pl provide some clarification to your answer

Comment: @SahilMittal it looks like your query forgot most of it's initial part the whole "update table" part was missing. If you only run "SET" mysql "thinks" you want to set a variable. So I assumed you simply missed that part. Hope that clarifies things